# JSOUP Website HTML Parsing : Java

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am stuck at a place where I need to parse [this](http://www.metacritic.com/game/playstation-3) website and display the **Top PlayStation 3 Games** by Metascore with their ratings. I am not able to come up with good parsing using JSoup as I just started developing using Jsoup.

I got the ratings and title like this. Any better ways ?

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
// To get score
Elements links = doc.select("span.metascore_w.medium.game");
// To get title
Elements links = doc.select("h3.product_title");
      for (Element link : links) {
        System.out.println("text : " + link.text());
      }
```

Comment: You can post your attempt at it to get a quicker resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this code :

```
Element div = doc.select("ol.list_products.list_product_summaries").first(); 
      for (Element element : div.children()) {
        System.out.println(element.select("span.metascore_w.medium.game").text());
        System.out.println(element.select("h3.product_title").text());
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

The other way you can look at is look for a repetitive parent for both the tags (like `div.main_stats`) you need and iterate over it gathering the elements:

```
Elements parents = doc.select("div.main_stats");
for (Element child : parents) {
    Element label = child.select("h3.product_title").first();
    Element score = child.select("span.metascore_w.medium.game").first();
System.out.println("Game **" + label.text()+ "** has a Metascore of ->> " + score.text());

}
```

**Output:**

```
Game **XCOM: Enemy Within** has a Metascore of ->> 88
Game **Minecraft: PlayStation 3 Edition** has a Metascore of ->> 86
Game **Gran Turismo 6** has a Metascore of ->> 81
Game **Need for Speed: Rivals** has a Metascore of ->> 80
```